# Holomorphic function has at most countably zeros

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic in a domain $U$, then $f$ has at most countably zeros.

How can I prove this statement? I have seen it in Sheng Gong  explicitly, but without any indications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the set $\{z\in U|f(z)=0\}$ were uncountable, then it would have an accumulation point (i.e. not be discrete), and thus you would have $f=0$ by the [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

Comment: Just to add on to this answer. Split $\mathbb{C}$ into a countable number of compact sets (not necessarily disjoint), forcing at least one of them to contains an infinite number of zeros, then apply metric compactness theorem to get accumulation point.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a direct proof.

We know zeros of an analytic function are isolated. You shall get the proof in any standard textbook of complex analysis.

So if $a$ and $b$ are two zeros of $f(z)$ with $a \neq b$ you shall get open subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ with $A \cap B = \phi$

Consider $a_1 + i a_2$ and $b_1 + i b_2$ in $A$ and $B$ with $a_i$, $b_i$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$. So you shall get an one to one correspondence between set of all zeros and a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thus set of all zeros of the analytic function are countable.