# But doesn't the exponential function not have zeros?????

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

There is some kind of analytic continuation theorem in complex analysis I don't understand, something about if a holomorphic function isn't identically zero, then it has an infinite countable set of zeros. I don't see a name for the theorem, I've only been told it in spoken language and then maybe have found similar theorems on the internet like here https://math.berkeley.edu/~vvdatar/m185f16/notes/Lecture-19_Zeroes.pdf.

But $e^{z}$ is holomoprhic and yet I have been told by several professors it has no zeros in the complex plane, so how is this not a contradiction with the alleged theorem? What is it actually saying?

It's related to this other question [Holomorphic function has at most countably zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625734/holomorphic-function-has-at-most-countably-zeros) but I am trying to understand it from this zero set argument. The question has "at most" but I don't see an "at most" in the PDF I linked to nor was I told "at most" in real life, just that the set of zeros of a holomorphic function is countable if it is not identically zero, which was used as a lemma to the fundamental theorem of algebra and that if there is always one zero of a power series of a holomorphic function for any order, then it must be polynomial.

Comment: An entire function of non integral order has infinitely many zeros as the exponential of an entire function has integral or infinite order

Comment: The phrase "integral order" has no meaning to me. Do you mean "integer" order? Because that is something that does make sense in this context since each term of the expansion of a Taylor series for a holomorphic function has an *integer* order.

Comment: I think you might be misremembering the identity theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem But also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem

Comment: An entire function has finite order if its absolute value is bounded by $e^{R^a}$ on discs of radius $R$ where $a$ is a finite constant and the infimum of such is called the order. Polynomials have order zero, $\cos \sqrt z$ has order $\frac{1}{2}$, $e^{z^k}$has order $k$ etc. It is an easy result that if an entire function has finitely many zeros (or any other value is taken finitely many times) then it must have integral order, so in particular entire functions of non integral order have infinitely many zeros

Comment: Okay, but I said "integral order" doesn't make sense to me, then you choose to ignore me to use that phrase again, so now everything you claim based off of that phrase also has no meaning. I'm not doing repeated integration, if anything, I'm doing repeated differentiation to define a Taylor series, so "integral" order shouldn't play a role here.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such theorem and neither the word “infinite” nor “countable” appear on that text that you linked. I suppose that there is a language issue here. For some authors, a set is countable if its cardinal is smaller than or equal to the cardinal of $\mathbb N$. But, if this is so, then finite sets are countable and, in particular, the empty set is contable. So, one can perfectly say that a function without zeroes (such as the exponential function) has finitely many zeroes.

Comment: I already know there can't be such a theorem because it's obviously a contradiction for many functions. The problem is I don't know *how* it's a contradiction given so many sites and books reference this seeming property. And no the countability interpretation is not issue at all. In older texts it is true countable was synonymous with being infinitely large but still having a 1-1 mapping to the set of all natural numbers, but nowadays mathematicians generally say "countably finite" or "countably infinite" to clear up the "less than or equal to" ambiguity.

Comment: Actually that's not true as the theory of entire functions of finite order which has lots of results that give not only infinite zeros but estimates of their number in a given radius shows (this was started by Hadamard for among other reasons to prove Riemann's assertion that RZ has infinitely many critical zeros and they are about $T\log T$ up to imaginary value $T$ - which is precisely the general result when an entire function has order 1 and maximal type)