# Let $f$ be holomorphic and $f(z)=0$ ($f$ is non zero). Show that for a small enough $r$ we have a $\delta$ s.t $|f(z)|>\delta$ for $|z|=r$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic and $f(z)=0$. Show that for a small enough $r$ we have a $\delta$ s.t $|f(z)|>\delta$
for $|z|=r$

I was looking at the proof of the Hurwitz theorem and this was a claim made in it [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)#:~:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20in%20particular,is%20named%20after%20Adolf%20Hurwitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20in%20particular,is%20named%20after%20Adolf%20Hurwitz)

I at first though that it might be some maximum modulus principle. However, that got me nowhere and I think i over-complicated it. I think that since $f$ is holomorphic the zeroes are separated. Now take $r$ small enough so that the circle does not hit any zeroes. Then  the circle is a compact set, so it achieves a minimum, which cannot be $0$ and so such $\delta$ exists.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Am i correct?

Comment: Do you mean $|f(z)|>\delta?$

Comment: @Caffeine Yes of course!

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is holomorphic and nonconstant, then its zeros are isolated. If we can find an $r$ such that $f(z)\not=0$ for all  $z\in Z_r$ where $Z_r = \{z :|z| = r\}$, then since $Z_r$ is a compact set, there exists $w\in Z_r$ so that $|f(w)| = \min_{z\in Z_r}|f(z)|$. As $f$ has no zeros on $Z_r$, we will have found our $\delta = \frac{|f(w)|}{2}$.

Suppose that there was no $r$ such that $z\in Z_r$ implied that $f(z)\not=0$ for all $z\in Z_r$. Then for each $r>0$ we could assign at least one zero labelled $z_r$ which has the property that $|z_r| = r$ and $f(z_r) = 0$. We now have an uncountable number of zeros for the function $f$. But an analytic function can only have uncountably many zeros if it is identically equal to zero (zee: [Holomorphic function has at most countably zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625734/holomorphic-function-has-at-most-countably-zeros)). Hence we have a contradiction and conclude that there must exists at least one $r > 0$ such that $f$ has no zeros on $Z_r$.

You can modify this argument with an arbitrary bound $\gamma$ to get the same result and shrink that bound to be arbitrarily small by considering all $r\in (0,\gamma)$ for which $f$ has no zeros on $Z_r$.