# zeroes of non-zero holomorphic function form an atmost countable set

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

One of my assignment questions which I could not solve was following.

> Question : If f is a holomorphic function on a region X which is not identically zero show that the zeroes of the function form an atmost countable set .

I was confused while solving the question . So I search MSE and found this solution :

[Holomorphic function has at most countably zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625734/holomorphic-function-has-at-most-countably-zeros)

Answer of User : Daniel Roberts says:"If the set {z∈U|f(z)=0} were uncountable, then it would have an accumulation point "

> My question: Why any uncountable set must have a limit point ? Can anyone please give a rigorious proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ be an infinite uncountable subset of $\Bbb C$. If $n\in\Bbb N$, let $U_n=U\cap\{z\in\Bbb C\mid|z|\leqslant n\}$. Suppose that $U_n$ is infinite. Then, since $U_n\subset\{z\in\Bbb C\mid|z|\leqslant n\}$ and since this last set is compact, $U_n$ has an accumulation there and, in particular, $U$ has an accumulation point.

So, if $U$ had no accumulation point, each $U_n$ would be finite. But $U=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$ and therefore $U$ would be countable.

Answer (score 1):

Decompose the complex plane into countable compact sets, say into closed balls of radius $n$, $B_n$. The complex plane,
$$C=\cup B_n$$ If $V$ is the set of zeroes, then $\cup (V\cap B_n)=V$. If all of the sets $V \cap B_n$ contained only countably many zeroes, then the whole set $V$ would be the countable union of countable sets and therefore, countable. So, one of these has uncountable zeroes. Use the compactness of $B_n$ to argue that they have an accumulation point.