# Be $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ an open and connected set. If $f \in A\mathbb{(\Omega)}$ and $f \neq 0$ show that the set of all zeros is numerable

Tags: complex-analysis

> Be $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ an open and connected set. If $f \in A\mathbb{(\Omega)}$ and $f \neq 0$ show that the set of all zeros is numerable.

I already demostrated by contradiction that $Z(f)$ is discrete, but I don't know how use it to demostrated that $Z(f)$ is numerable. Any hint please?.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3793068/zeroes-of-non-zero-holomorphic-function-form-an-atmost-countable-set or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625734/holomorphic-function-has-at-most-countably-zeros

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the links, now i understand what should I have done. But I have a doubt in the answers, what is the consistency in the fact of linking $a_{1} +ia_{2}$ with $Q$, I know that as $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable then $Z(f)$ is countable, but how can you get the linking of it? i think is because $Q$ is dense in $R$ right? if not, what is the theory?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be analytic and suppose that $z_0$ is a zero of $f$.

Then $f$ has a power series centered at $z_0$, that is, there exists $r > 0$ such that $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$ for all $z$ such that $|z-z_0|<r$.  Now there exist a minimal $N > 0$ such that $a_N \neq 0$ or else $f$ would be identically equal to $0$ by the uniqueness theorem for analytic functions.  Hence, $f(z) = \sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n = (z-z_0)^N\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^{n-N} = (z-z_0)^Ng(z)$.  Now $g(z)$ is continuous and $g(z_0) \neq 0$ so there exists a neighborhood of $z_0$ such that $g(z) \neq 0$ in this neighborhood. Hence each zero is isolated so just pick a rational in each such disk $\implies$ the zeros are countable.